# Degenerate Hecke algebra

Tags: representation-theory

> **Problem:** Define $H_2$, the degenerate Hecke algebra generated by $X_1, X_2, s$. Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Consider the following
>   matrices defining an action of $X_1, X_2$ on a 2-dimensional space
>   $L(a,b)$. $$X_1=\begin{bmatrix} a &  -1\\   0&  b \end{bmatrix},
>  X_2=\begin{bmatrix} b&1\\ 0&a \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> (i). Can $a=b$?
>
> (ii). Is $L(a,b)$ isomorphic to $L(b,a)$ (as representations of $H_2$ defined by the above actions) when $b\ne a\pm 1, a\ne b$?

I have considered the representation of the algebra $H_2$ given by the action of it's generators (with $s$ acting on the vector space by just transposing the two basis vectors $v_1,v_2$). All the relations (which define the Hecke algebra) hold for this choice of actions. But none of these relations say anything about equality between $a$ and $b$. I am stuck here. Please help.

Considering a suitable choice of basis vectors $\{v_1,v_3=v_2-v_1/(b-a)\}$, the matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$ are diagonal. We use the map $f:L(a,b)\to L(b,a)$ mapping $v_1\mapsto v_3$ and $v_3\mapsto v_1$. This is a linear map and we show $$f\circ X_1=X_1\circ f\\ f\circ X_2=X_2\circ f\\ f\circ s=s\circ f.$$ This is enough to show $L(a,b)\cong L(b,a)$.

Is my approach for (ii) right?